# 2000s (or earlier) young adult novel like "Ender's Game", genetically enhanced teenage boy trains in holographic battles to win an uncontaminated land

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a book about 10 years ago about a teenage boy that is in a government program for genetically enhanced children in a post-apocalyptic world. He is training for a holographic battle game against other countries where the winner gets the last piece of uncontaminated land.

He meets his partners, a girl about his age and a young boy who is crippled but a genius.

I don't remember much more than that but I have been looking for it for years. This is NOT *Ender's Game* or anything from that series, I have checked.

Comment: I find your emphatic "This is NOT Ender's Game" rather amusing.  The books are almost nothing alike, and have different authors, yet I too have somehow associated the two (along with a third book, "Virtual World" by Chris Westwood) with each other...

Comment: see OP (maybe?) comment below confirming (probably?) duplicate status.

Answer (score 10):

*Virtual War Chronologs* (1997) by Gloria Skurzynski.

From [this review](https://gloriabooks.com/virtual.html):

> By the year 2080, plague, disease, and nuclear war have confined Earth's two million human survivors to a few domed cities, where they are governed by the Western Hemisphere Federation, the Eurasian Alliance, or the Pan Pacific Coalition. When it is discovered that a small group of islands in the Pacific has become livable again, the three federations decide to wage a bloodless virtual war, with the winner to take possession of the island called Nuku Hiva.
>
> All his life Corgan, then fourteen, has trained to be the champion of the Western Federation. Genetically engineered for quick reflexes, superior physical condition, and a remarkable time-splitting ability, he's been raised in isolation inside a virtual reality Box..
>
> Only three weeks before the start of the War, Corgan meets - virtually - his two teammates: Brig, a ten-year-old mutant who is a superb strategist, and Sharla, the same age as Corgan. It is Sharla, with her brilliant ability to break codes, who brings him his first real human contact.

Comment: Oh my god thank you! You have no idea how long i have looked for this book!!!!

Comment: @Matt: Remember to accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: I have been looking for this book for the last 10 years!!! I couldn't remember half the information Matt posted, all I could remember was that they were genetically enhanced! Thank you so much! I was beginning to think I had dreamed up the entire book!